# reversing an array in javascript in function without method reverse()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

here is my code:

```js
const reverseArr = (...args) => {
  let length   = args.length - 1
  let reversed = []
  let i        = 0
  for (let a = length - i; i <= length; i++) {
    args[a] = reversed[i]
  }
  return reversed
}

console.log( reverseArr(3, 5, 4, 1) )
```

What's the problem here? Does it about value of 'i' or lenght?

Comment: `args[a] = reversed[i]` doesn’t make sense. `reversed` is empty and you never fill it with anything.

Comment: Your `args[a] = reversed[i]` assignment is backwards, and you never alter the value of `a` after its initialisation. Fix those two and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverse(arr){
// get length
var len = arr.length;
// create new array
var newArr = [];
// loop through array
for(var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    // push to new array
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
}
// return new array
return newArr;}
```

reverse([1,2,3,4,5]);

try this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues :

1. `for` initialisation happens once, so if you do `let a = lemgth - i`, it doesn't update a any further, even though `i` changes.
2. You're reassigning values to your input array itself with `reversed` array, which is empty itself.
3. You're output-ing the input array `(arr)`.

I tried to fix your snippet, and also adding better approach:

```js
const reverseArr = (...args) => {
      let length = args.length - 1
      let reversed = []
      let i = 0
      // update 'a' as soon as you update 'i'
      for(let a = length - i; i <= length; i++, a = length - i){
        // update the standby array 'reveresed'
        reversed[i] = args[a]
      }
      // print the reversed array instead of 'args' 
      console.log(reversed)
    }


// Alternate approach (in-place reverse)
const reverseInput = (...args) => {
  let left = 0, right = args.length - 1;
  while(left <= right) {
    // swap the left and right elements in  array
    [args[left], args[right]] = [args[right], args[left]] ;
    left++;
    right--;
  }
  console.log(args);
}

    // Approach 1
    console.log(reverseArr(3, 5, 4, 1))
    // Approach 2
    console.log(reverseInput(3,5,4,1));
```

Comment: thnx bud it worked i guess i missed to change the value of a right ? did you like my approach as a beginner and which approach do you prefer and why ?

Comment: `reverseArr = (...args) => {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      newArr.unshift(args[i]);
  }
  console.log(newArr);
}

reverseArr(3, 5, 4, 1)` also this one is great solution i think

Comment: @KeremUYSAL this looks good, but if you think about time complexity, this solution takes O(n^2), (one for loop and `unshift` operation), considering that I prefer the `Approach 2` with 2 pointers, doing the same job in O(n) complexity

Answer (score 0):

simply...

```js
const reverseArr = (...args) => Array.from({length:args.length},_=>args.pop())
 
console.log( reverseArr(3, 5, 4, 1) )
```

if you want to use an array as argument and let it untouched:

```js
const reverseArr = arr => Array.from({length:arr.length},(_,i)=>arr[(arr.length-++i)])


let arrOrigin = [3,5,4,1]
let arrResult = reverseArr( arrOrigin )

console.log( arrOrigin )
console.log( arrResult )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i have some issues with first one. can you explain a bit. what is the curly braces after from and do you select the last element of the array with the pop

Comment: @KeremUYSAL It's in the docs:  `Array.from({length:3})` make an array of 3 undefined elements, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const reverse = (array) => {
    const reversed = [];
    for (const [index, element] of numbers.entries())
        reversed[array.length - index - 1] = element;
    return reversed;
}

console.log(reverse(numbers)); // [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

We can use a `for ... of` loop on the entries of the array we want to reverse, and push the element into the desired position of the array.

To calculate the position we want, we can just do `array length - index - 1`.

This means that if we have an array of 5 items, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and we iterate through, we will be doing...

1. `5 - 0 - 1 = 4` for the index of the first item.
2. `5 - 1 - 1 = 3` for the index of the second item.
3. `5 - 2 - 1 = 2` for the index of the third item.
4. `5 - 3 - 1 = 1` for the index of the fourth item.
5. `5 - 4 - 1 = 0` for the index of the fifth item.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
function reversearr(...args) {
let reversed = args
args.forEach((x, y) => {reversed[-(y+1)]=x})
}
```

Comment: whats the value of 'x' here ? when run the code it gives double amount of elements in array also

Comment: x is each item you get when looping through args.

Answer (score -2):

In javascript you can reverse an array with `sort` function

```
function reverseArr(a){
 return a.sort((a,b)=>b-a)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't reverse the array, rather it... well... sorts it...